# CakePHP Route for API

Tags: php, api, cakephp, routes

Basically i'm developing an API with cake and I'd like to put some version control in my URL to make upgrading the API easier later on.

I'm not looking for any fancy routes at the moment, simply that the route

domain.com/api/1.9/:controller works.

I'm having a hard time getting this to work. At the moment simple requests work, but sending a POST request to domain.com/api/1.0/pictures/ fails.

Comment: How are you defining your routes?

Comment: At the moment only these:
  Router::connect('/api/1.0/:controller/:action', array());
  
  #RESTful router aan!
  Router::mapResources('ratings');
  Router::mapResources('pictures');
  Router::parseExtensions('xml', 'json');

Comment: Does sending a post to `domain.com/api/1.0/pictures (*Notice no trailing slash*) work?

Comment: be careful that that dot in your version isn't triggering extension parsing.  if i were you i'd go integer for version, ala v1/v2/v3

Comment: @joeb No this gives me: `Error: ApiController could not be found.`

Comment: Is it possible to use API versioning with the different section(admin/client)?
I want a working URL like https://myproject.com/api/v2/admin/product/edit/5, so this will call "product's" admin_v2_api_edit method or something like this. @Ezra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frank Mullenger has the best solution for a versioned CakePHP API that I have found. He's posted a three-part series that makes good use of Cake's routing and some custom API methods.

[First part (the problem with un-versioned APIs)](http://deadlytechnology.com/php/api-cakephp-app/)

[Second part (the solution for CakePHP)](http://deadlytechnology.com/php/cakephp-api-component/)

[Third part (error handling)](http://deadlytechnology.com/php/api-error-handling/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought about doing what you want without using clever routing, but you would need to change up the rest call URL a little.

instead of

```
domain.com/api/1.0/pictures/$param1/$param2/$etc
```

try

```
domain.com/api/pictures/1.0/$param1/$param2/$etc
```

then in the controller,

```
class Pictures extends controller {
  ....
  function pictures( $ver , $param1, $param2, $etc) {
    switch($ver) {
      case '1.3':
        $this->setAction('pictures_1-3', $param1, $param2, $etc);
        break;
      case '1.2':
        $this->setAction('pictures_1-2', $param1, $param2, $etc);
        break;
      case '1.1':
      default:
        $this->setAction('pictures_1-1', $param1, $param2, $etc);
        break;
     }
   }

   function pictures_1-3() {}
   function pictures_1-2() {}
   function pictures_1-1() {}
}
```

Comment: That seems like it would add a ton of unnecessary code to your controllers. It shouldn't be the job of any one controller to handle multiple APIs.

Comment: well, it depends on if you need to support multiple versions of the API in parallel. For example, the Direct3D API, There is a function Direct3DCreate9 to create the rendering context. There's also Direct3DCreate8, Direct3DCreate7, ... etc. They all still work. If you can dictate API changes to your customers with out much grumbling (ala Facebook) then that's the cleanest way. If you have to support more than one at the same time, then it's duplicate code in the controller. If not the controller, then the model. It's going to have to go somewhere. (Please god no C++ style IFDEFs!) :D

Comment: @joeb: You can easily create a generic form of that function and embed it in your AppController.

Comment: I'd rather see someone put the different APIs into a plugin specific for the version it corresponds to. That way each one lives separate of one another.

Comment: i don't think the DX api is a good role model for *any* development, @zeroSkillz. personally, i would put them in prefix-routed methods, unless they were significantly different, whereupon i'd do what @joeb suggested and put them in a plugin.

Comment: @jmcneese oh good god no, i would never hold the DirectX API as a paragon of coding excellence, merely illustrating the business need of maintaining two working APIs in parallel.

Comment: Is it possible to use API versioning with the different section(admin/client)?
I want a working URL like https://myproject.com/api/v2/admin/product/edit/5, so this will call "product's" admin_v2_api_edit method or something like this. @zeroSkillz